# Can't load an specific image with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to open fancybox with an image.

Here's the code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wg4MD/430/)):

```
$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {
    var url='http://files.parse.com/773ee808-4477-4c78-9763-cbd6b532d477/a69470fc-c6be-45b7-a424-312a6b711d01-PhotoImage';
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            href : url,                
            title : '1st title'
        },

    ], {
        padding : 0,fitToView: false,autoSize:false
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Please include relevant code that you are having an issue with, what you have tried, and the results. Pasting just a link to jsfiddle is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `type` of content you are trying to open (`image` in this case) within the script like :

```
$(".open_fancybox").click(function () {
    var url = 'http://files.parse.com/773ee808-4477-4c78-9763-cbd6b532d477/a69470fc-c6be-45b7-a424-312a6b711d01-PhotoImage';
    $.fancybox.open([{
        href: url,
        title: '1st title',
        type: "image" // tell fancybox the type of content
    },

    ], {
        padding: 0,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false
    });

    return false;

});
```

why? because your variable `url` doesn't have an `image` extension (`gif|jpg|png`) so fancybox can't figure out is an `image`.

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f6QZL/)</kbd>

For further information, you can refer to :

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==>FAQ tab ==> No. 5